# How to select input tag on keypress

Tags: javascript, html, input

Hey I have a list of input tags , I am navigating through all input tags using arrowUp and arrowDown keys I want to select input tag on pressing enter key and start typing.

```
<input type="text" /> selected and start typing on keypress enter
```

Comment: I think it's default behavior of inputs, you can type in it when it focused

Comment: but we can only start typing after clicking on input tag I want to start type on keypress enter

Comment: Now we know what you want to do, but what is your programming related question?

Comment: You said you are switching inputs by arrows keys, so you store current input element in any wariable ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var el = document.getElementById("myInputID");
el.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        // Enter key was hit
    }
});
```

Comment: no this won't work. actually I want 5 input tags in a row in which I can navigate using arrow keys and select any input tag by pressing enter key

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <input type="text" id="text1"><script>
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (event)=>{if (event.key == 'Enter') {document.getElementById("text1").focus()} })</script>
```

but this works only if you have one element

Answer (score 0):

let's imagine you have `<div class="container">` with list of inputs:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" value="1">
    <input type="text" value="2">
    <input type="text" value="3">
</div>

    document.getElementById('container').querySelectorAll('input').forEach((node) => {
      node.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
          // your logic here
        }
      })
    })
```